# Want to be a developer

Tags: qa-developer, career-development

Currently I am a quality engineer and I am working as automation and white box tester. I create automation suite in java and do white box test of java application how can I jump to java or J2ee development whether I have to do any side projects to show my development experience?

Answer (score 1):

This is a interesting question. I can share my route of becoming Dev from QA.

- For a product two things are important - Functional Knowledge & Technical Expertise. After working couple of years I become subject matter expert for my product.
- I was looped in for all design discussions. It was mutually beneficial to share technical functional expertise and technical learnings.
- When I wanted to move to DEV, I was asked to focus on some of DEV Skills to ramp up. Also, there was no open position as well at that point
- After working on for couple of months there was opportunity due to attrition in Dev Team. This was a great opportunity with plus for Functional Expertise and focussed learnings for Dev
- It was quite challenging and a great learning in Dev role, I recommend move to DEV within your current project as you would have functional advantage of product